# return key from array by comparing values

Tags: php, arrays, comparison, sorting

I have 3 arrays, one has low value weight, the other high value weights, the third: the actual value for that weight 'bracket':

```
Array 1
(
    [0] => 0.00
    [1] => 2.00
    [2] => 5.00
    [3] => 20.00
    [4] => 50.00
    [5] => 100.00
)
Array 2
(
    [0] => 1.90
    [1] => 4.90
    [2] => 20.00
    [3] => 50.00
    [4] => 100.00
)
Array 3
(
    [0] => 30
    [1] => 50
    [2] => 100
    [3] => 200
    [4] => 500
    [5] => 1000
)
```

I need to find the corresponding KEY from Array 3, where my value (lets say 5.30) is greater than a value in array 1 but less than its corresponding value in array 2 (greater than 5 but less than 20). The result of this example would produce the array key of [2] from Array 3 and the value of 100.

I could loop through each array and find the keys, but Im hoping there is a faster way to do this, by somehow merging the arrays:

```
    [2] =>  
        [0] => 5.00
        [1] => 20.00
        [2] => 100
```

...and then seeing if my value is between [0] and [1], if so return [2]
Basically [2][0] is 'from' weight, [2][1] is 'to' weight and the value for that 'bracket' is [2][2].

Merged Array using example code:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0.00
            [1] => 1.90
            [2] => 30
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2.00
            [1] => 4.90
            [2] => 50
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5.00
            [1] => 20.00
            [2] => 100
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20.00
            [1] => 50.00
            [2] => 200
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 50.00
            [1] => 100.00
            [2] => 500
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 100.00
            [1] => 
            [2] => 100
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be so much easier if your input data was not structured in such an unfortunate manner.

Anyway, if you want to do this *fast* then the appropriate solution is probably manual looping:

```
// possibly add some error checking
foreach($lows as $i => $low) {
    if ($value >= $low && isset($highs[$i]) && $value <= $highs[$i]) {
        return $values[$i];
    }
}
```

To do what you ask for (merge the arrays), you can use `array_map`:

```
$merged = array_map(
          function($low, $high = null, $value) {
              return func_get_args();
          },
          $lows, $highs, $values);
```

And then:

```
foreach($bands as $band) {
    if($value >= $band[0] && $band[1] && $value <= $band[1]) {
        return $band[2];
    }
}
```

Comment: what would an ideal structure be for this example?

Comment: @Innate: Something like what you want to do in the end :)

Comment: I guess that changes my question then, with the new array, what would be the fastest way to return the value?

Comment: @Innate: Pretty much the same as the first approach. I updated the answer.

Comment: Excellent answer Jon, thank you. I've wrapped this up in a function an successfully applied it. Thank you.